# How can I skip or remove a list of html tags from my crawler object using Symfony DomCrawler Component and Goutte for Laravel 4?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4, goutte

This was my first attempt but it did not work.

```
$this->crawler = $client->request('GET', $this->url);
$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$root = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('_root'));
$this->crawler->rewind();
$root->appendChild($document->importNode($this->crawler->current(), true));

$selectorsToRemove = ['script','p'];
foreach ($selectorsToRemove as $selector) {
   $crawlerInverse = $this->crawler->filter($selector);
   foreach ($crawlerInverse as $elementToRemove) {
      $parent = $elementToRemove->parentNode;
      $parent->removeChild($elementToRemove);
    }
}
$this->crawler->clear();
$this->crawler->add($document);
```

I want to get the "p" tags from this page [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00IOY8XWQ/ref=fs_kv](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IOY8XWQ) and it seams that it has some js inside the paragraph so when I try to do $node->text(); it gets me the text and the js inside the "script" inside the "p". The structure is like this;

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
<script>
 "JS CODE"
</script>
</p>
```

So I just want the Lorem ipsum text.

Comment: DomCrawler is for crawling, not for editing. Use the plain DOMDocument for editing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at DomCrawler and don't see a whole lot of purpose in it. It seems to just be wrapping around the already-plenty-easy-to-use [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), so I'm going to take a short-cut and use that directly instead.

The example is short and simple, you should be able to adapt it more or less as-is. You've got a DOMDocument ready to go.

---

#### Example:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
<script>
 "JS CODE"
</script>
</p>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//p/script') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

---

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

</p>
```